# How could I query average and group by using LINQ in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am a beginner of C#. I am familiar with SQLstatement, but not good in LINQ. Now what I need to do is using a LINQ statement query `booking.PackageId` and `AvG(booking.Rating)` Grouping by `booking.Package`. (I need to display the average rating according to different `PackageID`).

[Here is my booking table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jP6f.png)

I want to use a listview for displaying all information

```
   <asp:ListView 
   ID="lvBookings" runat="server" 
   DataKeyNames="BookingId" 
   ItemType="TravelPlannerSystem.Models.Booking" 
   SelectMethod="GetFeedbacks">
```

This is my code behind for `GetFeedbacks`

```
public IQueryable<Booking> GetFeedbacks()
{
    var db = new TravelPlannerContext();
    var query = from booking in db.Bookings
              group booking by booking.PackageId into grouping
              select new {
              PackId = grouping.Key,
              AverageRating = grouping.Average(ed => ed.Rating)
              };
    return query;
}
```

It keeping gives me the error, I have been searching online for 2 days. I really don't know how to make change on this. Could anyone help here?

Comment: Please add the error you are getting so it is clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that your function is expecting a return value of `IQueryable<Booking>` but you are returning `IQueryable<AnonymousType>`: Your projection (the `select` part) is creating a `new {}` which is an anonymous type with `PackId` and `AverageRating`.

This new type is not the `Booking` type and is why it is failing.

What you should do, as you can't return an anonymous type (and I think using dynamics here wouldn't be a good practice) is to create a new class and then:

```
public IQueryable<YourClass> GetFeedbacks()
{    
    return from booking in (new TravelPlannerContext()).Bookings
           group booking by booking.PackageId into grouping
           select new YourClass // Now you are projecting the expected type
           {
               PackId = grouping.Key,
               AverageRating = grouping.Average(ed => ed.Rating) ?? 0
           };
}
```

See how both the rerurn value and the projection are of the same type

Comment: Thank you, Gilad. But after I replace your code inside my file, I got a new error under (ed => ed.Rating), says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double?'  to 'double'. An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)".

Comment: The error is explaining it good... What is the type of your `AverageRating` field? and what is the type of your `Rating` field?. In any case see update :)

Comment: Here is my Rating field which was generated by create entity framework : public Nullable<double> Rating { get; set; }  . Here is my averageRating field which was set up by myself: public double AverageRating { get; set; }

Comment: Can I know why the "?? 0" is necessary?

Answer (score -1):

Try to convert this query .to before it passed to the view. use Tolist() to convert.